# How to downgrade libmysqlclient

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, libmysql

I just built a new dev box with Ubuntu 10.04.1 amd64 server on, installed all all libraries and stuff , but now my program segfaults randomly in libmysqlclient16.

Just to eliminate things I tried to downgrade to libmysqlclient15, as this is the version I initially developed against.

However no matter what I do in the lines of apt-get remove --purge libmysqlclient16-dev , when I try to apt-get install libmysqlclient15-dev afterwards , I always jsut end up with libmysqlclient16 again ?!

Help? Please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pin a version in /etc/apt/preferences:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto

(However, this question should be asked at superuser.com.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe link  libmysqlclient15 statically or make sure that you link exactly libmysqlclient15, not  libmysqlclient ?